# How to change Fullcalendar day's in month

Tags: javascript, jquery, persian-calendar

I'm working with Fullcalendar and faced this problem.I need to work with [Solar Hijri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar) calendar which each month in first six month of year contains 31 day and second six month each contains 30 days but Fullcalendar is in Gregorian Date and some of its month are in 28 day and some are in 30 day.also I used [moment-jalaali](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) to mimic momentjs api's but still that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Farid I added Jalaali calendar to version 2.6.0 you can find it from here:
https://github.com/ehsandanesh/fullcalendar

Comment: Thank you so much @golden_boy615.That's a dire need for Iranian people who want's  to work with Fullcalendar.Great job. :)